# Malformed print statements when running "ssh -t" with subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I currently have a script that runs a command on a remote server via

```py
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "host", "-t", ...etc], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I need to be able to kill the process spawned by this ssh call at will, which when I terminate the ssh session created with the `-t` flag, is no problem. However, when I attempt to print anything in the program at any point after the ssh call, the output is malformed.

```
everything
    looks
        like
            this
```

I believe this is due to extra carriage returns. I am currently stuck as I cannot get rid of the `-t` or the process is not killed, and have yet to find a way to disable whatever this subprocess call is doing to my terminal.

Is there a workaround to stop the subprocess from affecting my entire terminal like this?

Comment: Not _extra_, but _missing_. It means you have linefeeds and no carriage returns, but you have a terminal configured to expect both (as is usually done on Windows but not UNIXy systems).

Comment: `stty sane` is your friend to reset your terminal to a default configuration. Obviously, you'll want to do that only after the subprocess in question exits, since it's presumably configuring your terminal that way because its output will only be displayed correctly in that configuration.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm attempting to execute `os.system('stty sane')` before the execution of the ssh call, but it doesn't seem to help. Same if I execute it manually before executing the entire python script or after the ssh call.

Comment: **After**, not before. The point of `stty sane` is that it puts things back to the default configuration, after what's on the other side of your ssh connection sets it to something non-default.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I may have edited it after you saw, but I also did that, same result

Comment: BTW, there's a very good chance that the terminal control content messing with things are going over stderr. Redirect stderr in addition to stdout and it won't reach your tty (though it's also likely `-t` will stop having its desired meaning there, until/unless you change it to `-tt`). That said... what's the context in which you want to use both `-t` and `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`? Usually it's one or the other, since the former is for connecting your remote process to your terminal more comprehensively, and the latter is for redirecting its output _away from_ the default/inherited stdin

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you're right. After removing both pipe declarations, the stdout works completely normally. stderr is the only one experiencing the issue. If I execute a `stty sane` at the end of all execution, it *does* place things back into order, but it's honestly not an ideal solution if only because I want the feedback from the program to be completely live, and other functions within the program to not be affected while it runs. So executing an stty sane every milisecond seems hacky.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245670/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-laif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `unbuffer` program to execute the `ssh -t` call fixes the malformed output.

```py
subprocess.Popen(["unbuffer", "ssh", "host", "-t", ...etc], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The problem was caused by a mismatch in how the cursor is moved. This workaround causes the terminal to behave as expected.